# Web audio api, streaming a WAV file, i hear the "transition" between sources (that hold audio chunks)

Tags: javascript, php, streaming, web-audio-api

I'm stuck on a problem using audio web api. This is the final code after testing almost all the most used browsers, desktop and mobile. I tried other approaches, but this works for all. Problem is this is not immediate and i hear the very small transition between end of previous source and next, and so on with next calls.

Thanks for the help!

In window.load I load first samples from WAV using xmlhttprequest and arraybuffer, i create first source and source.start() when i click a button on my html page. While playing, i load next samples, so at the end of first source, i try to play second source (filled by another xmlhttprequest).

```
source.start();
    source.onended = function() {
    //volume2.gain.setTargetAtTime(1, 10.5, 0.015); // buffers are 10seconds
    source2.start();
    source2.onended = function() {
        source3.start();
    }
}
```

ok, this is the final approach, but i tried another before (code is after call of decoding of arraybuffer of xmlhttprequest request.response that is returned by a call to PHP code that seeks into the WAV file end does ECHO of the bytes):

```
audio0buf32 = buffer.getChannelData(0);
audio1buf32 = buffer.getChannelData(1);

audiobuf.copyToChannel(audio0buf32,0);
audiobuf.copyToChannel(audio1buf32,1);
```

audiobuf is created before this copy (with the full length of WAV file), in window.load

the second call while first sound is playing:

```
precaudio0buf32_length += audio0buf32.length; // the buffer length of previous call (previuos     length)
precaudio1buf32_length += audio1buf32.length;

precaudio0buf32_length and precaudio1buf32_length are initialized to 0 before first call.

audio0buf32 = buffer.getChannelData(0);
audio1buf32 = buffer.getChannelData(1);

audiobuf.copyToChannel(audio0buf32,0,precaudio0buf32_length);
audiobuf.copyToChannel(audio1buf32,1,precaudio1buf32_length);
```

copied with offset, ok. I tried with FireFox and Safari, but sound stops at the end of first source.start(), even if i do: (but I read something about this, and maybe this is me not doing things in the right way).

```
source = context.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = audiobuf; // the updated buffer
source.connect(context.destination);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use onended to start playing the next chunk.  There will always be gaps like that.  You really need to plan ahead and use the time parameter to start() in order to ensure that the audio playback is seamless; instead of chunk2.start() inside chunk1's onended, you need to remember when you start playing the first chunk, and then for each subsequent chunk, call start( time_previous_chunk_was_played + length_of_previous_chunk).  You can do this any time before the first chunk ends, as soon as you get the next chunk's data in.

Comment: Ok, i finished right now to use your suggestion, i cutted the onended instructions, and i wrote precCurrentTime = context.currentTime; source.start(); after, i wrote source2.start(precCurrentTime + 10); (in xmlhttprequest onload function) and it seems playback is very fluid, no gaps